# Trying to find neighbouring buffers in R with poly2nb()

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I want to get a list of neighbours for each buffer. However the returning `nb` list is empty.

```
require(sf)
require(spdep)

us <- tidycensus::county_laea 
us <-  st_sf(county_laea) %>% st_transform(, crs = 3857)
us$cent <- st_as_sf(st_centroid(us$geometry))
us$buff <- st_as_sf(st_buffer(us$cent, dist = 100000)) # buffer setting is 100km 

plot(st_geometry(us$geometry))
plot(st_geometry(us$cent), pch =4, add=T)
plot(st_geometry(us$buff), add=T, border = "red")

nb <- spdep::poly2nb(us$buff, queen = FALSE)


>nb
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 3143 
Number of nonzero links: 0 
Percentage nonzero weights: 0 
Average number of links: 0
```

When I run `poly2nb()` on `us$geometry` everything is fine:

```
us <- tidycensus::county_laea 
us <-  st_sf(county_laea) %>% st_transform(, crs = 3857)

nb <- spdep::poly2nb(us$geometry, queen = FALSE)

> nb
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 3143 
Number of nonzero links: 17572 
Percentage nonzero weights: 0.1778822 
Average number of links: 5.590837 
7 regions with no links:
2788 2836 2995 3135 3140 3141 3143
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running a rook (not queen) style neighborhood list on a bunch of circular buffers getting an empty list result is expected behaviour.

This is what your `us$buff` object looks like when zoomed in:

[image: a bunch of circular buffers]

Now think again about the definition of rook style neighborhood: two polygons are neighbors if & when they share a boundary consisting of more than one point (one point would be sufficient for queen). When in doubt I always think of Colorado and Arizona - they are queen type neighbors, but not rook type ones.

Given that all your buffer objects are circles they can touch their neighbor at most in a single point. Overlap does not make a boundary, and touching in a single point is ruled out by the rook settings.

On the other hand when you look at the original counties / the `us$geometry` object you will see a plenty of touching lines, and few rare occasions of touching points.

Which is why the queen vs. rook settings rarely makes a noticeable difference for organically grown admin areas, but a big one for grid based ones.

[image: original counties dataset]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Jindra So if I understood you correctly I should    try `queen = TRUE`. However this still gives me an empty nb list – can you point out a solution for me?

Comment: I meant that I strongly suggest using neighbors of the raw counties - rook or queen matters little - rather than buffered centroids. I can't think of any scenario where it would make sense to calculate centroids, buffer them and only then do the neighborhood lists